# Redirecting command line output, including text prompts for user input C#

Tags: c#, process, console, command

Many days I'm googling for this question, but did not found any answers.
I have batch file like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO This is sample output.
SET /P uname=Please enter your name: 
IF "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
ECHO Hello %uname%, Welcome to DOS inputs!
GOTO End
:Error
ECHO You did not enter your name! Bye bye!!
:End
pause
```

How we can see from this command, it will print "This is sample output." line and then will ask user for a name. On C#  "This is sample output." line will be received as output data, but the text "Please enter your name: " we receive only after inputting some thing in console. 
So, how we can receive prompt output before inputting something, can we redirect full console? (if we can say so).
Below is the test application.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CommandExecuter
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var start = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"C:\run.cmd",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                };

                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = start;
                    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += process_ErrorDataReceived;

                    process.Start();

                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    process.WaitForExit();

                    process.CancelOutputRead();
                    process.CancelErrorRead();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to execute command: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                Console.Write("OutputDataReceived: " + e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        private static void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                Console.Write("ErrorDataReceived: " + e.Data + Environment.NewLine);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if to a while.  I think you are getting multiple return lines

```css
      private static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                Console.Write("OutputDataReceived: " + e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

​
```

Comment: If we change if to while, then it will never ends, because we always will have true in while, if e.Data is not null or empty.

Comment: Not true.  If the string is null, you will exit the loop.  The problem is you have two strings in the input buffer and you are only getting the first string with the 'if'.  You have to flush both strings from the buffer , otherwise it appears that you are getting the wrong message displayed (previous message).

Comment: For my example e.Data is not null, so while will loop forever.
Also e.Data will not contain "Please enter your name: " data until anything will be sanded to the process stream input.